# Print menu after selection

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the menu again after someone enters a number (selects an option) on the same menu except for 5 which means quit. How can I do this? It has to print whatever it is in that option plus the menu again.

```
def main():
        choice = '0'
        while choice == '0':
            print("Welcome to the Game!")
            print("1) Sort by Value")
            print("2) Sort by ID")
            print("3) Find Card")
            print("4) New Hand")
            print("5) Quit")

            choice = input("Please make a selection: ")

        if choice == "5":
            print("Thanks for Playing!")
        elif choice == "4":
            pass
        elif choice == "3":
            pass
        elif choice == "2":
            for i in range(1, 31):
                myCard = Card(i)
                print(myCard)
        elif choice == "1":
            myDeck = Deck()
            print(myDeck)
        else:
            print("I don't understand your choice.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your if-statements in while-loop. And your while-loop condition should not be '0' if you intend to make '5' be quitting the game.

How about you create a function called `print_menu()`, and call it every time when you need it?

```py
def print_menu():
    print("1) Sort by Value")
    print("2) Sort by ID")
    print("3) Find Card")
    print("4) New Hand")
    print("5) Quit")

def main():

    print("Welcome to the Game!")
    print_menu()

    while True:
        choice = input("Please make a selection: ")

        if choice == '5':
            print("Thanks for Playing!")
            break
        elif choice == '4':
            print_menu()
            # something
        elif choice == '3':
            print_menu()
            # something
        elif choice == '2':
            print_menu()
            # something
        elif choice == '1':
            print_menu()
            # something
        else:
            print("I don't understand your choice.")
            print_menu()
```